# Access unordered_map stored in value of an unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm attempting to store unordered_maps inside one larger unordered_map, but I'm having difficulty trying to access these inner maps. I've posted an example of what I'm trying to do below.

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, string>> outermap;
outermap[0][0] = "whatever";
```

Any help on why this doesn't work would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It was an error related to how I was accessing the key, just spotted it. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles just fine with VC 2013:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, string>> outermap;
    outermap[0][0] = "whatever";
}
```

So, possible causes of your problem:

1. You have not shown us the real code.
2. You forgot to include `<unordered_map>`.
3. You forgot `using namespace std`. Of course, you should consider just prepending the names with `std::` anyway!
4. Your compiler does not support C++11.
5. Your definition of "doesn't work" is not the same as mine.

Comment: Ugh, it was a problem with something else with how I was attempting to find use the key (you would've spotted it if I had posted the full code). Sorry for the trouble!